# My Google Cloud Compute Engine Wordpress based website keeps askiing for more cpus and more memory - GBs of it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine, cpu-usage

I have a website that has had about the same traffic all year, yet on the GC Compute Engine page it keeps asking for more and more resources. Right now it has

n1-highmem-16 (16 vCPUs, 104 GB memory)

and is asking to increase to 20 vCPUs and 160 GBs memory

It gets about 25k visitors a month.

I use Wordfence Premium to keep it safe, and have even had their techs look into it but they see nothing. Yet it wants more and more and slows down to the point I get DB Connection errors.

Hacked? Maybe but no one sees anything wrong. Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: How much memory is it actually using, and how much is free? What is using the memory? Do you have appropriate memory and thread limits on PHP, which is quite CPU and memory intensive? That server seems like it has massive resources already. When you say 25K visitors per month, how many requests per second / minute / hour is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

As Tim advised on his comment, you will need to investigate your VM further. You said that you are getting a DB Connection error, you can start there and identify first its root cause. Also, recommendations are just suggestions based on the performance of your VM. As stated in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances#resizing_instances_according_to_recommendations):

> Note: You might have valid reasons for running a particular instance
> at very low or very high utilization. Sizing recommendations are
> suggestions to help you more efficiently use your instances, but they
> might not be appropriate for every situation.

For a more precise monitoring of your VM, you can use a [Cloud Monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent). It can access system resources and app services for a more detailed monitoring that can help you identify what is causing the unusual resource consumption.